# Convert a string with some ASCII code in PHP

Tags: php, ascii, conventions

I don't know if this question has been already asked! It really seems to be new!
I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526192/convert-a-string-containing-ascii-to-unicode), but it is for *Java*, not *PHP*.

Here follows my problem.
On the client-side, I'm using TinyMCE to get a long text. On the server-side, I extract the first n words from that string for listing purpose.

In particular, the string returned contains HTML code, that I remove by using the PHP `strip_tags()` function, and **it also contains ASCII characters** (e.g. `&nbsp;` for spaces).

Is there any PHP function that automatically convert all the ASCII contained in a string or capable to detect all the ASCII code in a string?

In the first case all would be easy; in the latter I should find the ASCII and then replace it with the `chr()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the function [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

From the documentation :

> html_entity_decode() is the opposite of htmlentities() in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

Comment: Does it returns a string with "-" as separator?

Comment: Why would it? It replaces html centities to the corresponding character. `&nbsp;` becomes a space, `&amp;` becomes &, etc.

Comment: Sorry! My question was related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530238/convert-ascii-and-utf-8-to-non-special-characters-with-one-function) accepted answer. The author shown that the result was the string with the words separated by "-". Thanks! Your answer will be accepted!